# Reset Azure VM Password for Local Administrator Account

Tags: azure, remote-access, rdp, azure-virtual-machine, change-password

I was trying to change the local admin account's password, but mistakenly checked the change password on next login and as a result of that I can no longer RDP to the machine.

I'm trying to reset the user credentials from Azure Powershell, but can't seem to get it working.

I've followed this article: http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/06/26/microsoft-azure-virtual-machines-reset-forgotten-admin-password-with-windows-powershell.aspx

Although I didn't see any errors in the console throughout the process, I still can't RDP to the VM.

Here is the screenshot of what I get when I try to RDP in:

[image]

For some reason, VM doesn't show up under Virtual Machines (classic) on Azure Portal, and unfortunately reset password interface of the new Virtual Machines tab says it's coming soon.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand for what reason your VM doesn't show up under Virtual Machines (classic) on Azure new Portal. However, even you can't see your VM in the new portal, you can still use the new portal to reset your password.

1. log into the [classic portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/).
2. find your VM in **Virtual Machines**, and click it.
3. Click **Dashboard**, and under the **quick glance**, click **Reset password (new portal)**

   [image]
4. Now, you can reset your password in the new portal.

   [image]
5. If resetting password does not work in your case, try **Reset Remote configuration (new portal)** first. And then reset you password.